# 404 | Not Found | InvalidArgumentException Cannot redirect to an empty URL

Tags: symfony-1.4

I copied the live  project on line server to local drive, after user login, this error was comming.

i tried login using /frontend_dev.php instead of index.php.

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Update your post with the full stack trace (error log).

Comment: stack trace > At sfAction->redirect( null)
>   Apps/frontend/modules/main/actions/action.class. Php line 84 this is the line 84  sfConfig::get('app_sf_guard_plugin_success_signin_url_'.$group)

Comment: Could you add in your **question post** information about `/frontend/modules/main/actions/action.class` around line 84, and where you defined `$group`.

Comment: sfGuardGroup:
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  columns:
    name:
      type: string(255)
      unique: true
    description: string(1000)
  relations:
    Users:
      class: sfGuardUser
      refClass: sfGuardUserGroup
      local: group_id
      foreign: user_id
      foreignAlias: Groups
    Permissions:
      class: sfGuardPermission
      local: group_id
      foreign: permission_id
      refClass: sfGuardGroupPermission
      foreignAlias: Groups

Comment: hi,i defined the group in  function setCredential($username) $group = $user->getGroups()->getFirst()->getName();

Answer (score 0):

If your group name is "visitor", check if you have a sf_guard_plugin_success_signin_url_visitor key in your app.yml file

Since that is returning empty, it is being routed to empty URL